# Die Verwendung des Modalverbs „sollen“ in Präteritum und Konjunktiv 2

Tags: subjunctive, modal-verb, preterite

Ich habe den folgenden Satz gehört/gelesen: **„Ich sollte das nicht essen“**. 
Meiner Meinung nach könnte dieser Satz 2 unterschiedliche Übersetzungen haben, und zwar: **„I shouldn’t eat that.“** und auch **„I wasn’t supposed to eat that.“** 
Gegeben das, die Präteritum und Konjunktiv 2 Formen des Verbs „sollen“ gleich sind, wie wählt man die richtige Übersetzung von der Beiden oben überhaupt aus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Du hast völlig recht. Beide Deutungen sind möglich.

Welche davon zutrifft, kann man nur aus dem Zusammenhang erschließen.